# Connecting different content types/tables in Drupal with primary/foreign keys

Tags: database

I am using Drupal 7 and I want to create tables which have primary key and foreign keys using content types. Each table would be created using content types. Let's say, when I create Fruit content type, it should create a table for it, right? Then, I may have Price table, hence, I create a Price content type. Now, the Fruit id(primary key) should be connected with Fruit id in the Price table (content type). How's this possible? I don't know how to code the tables/content type schema.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be great to have this feature. I always think it's backward to make a db abstraction layer that removes functionality and makes things inefficient just to help in the one off chance you'll ever want to change your database back end...

Answer (score 2):

Following link has a long discussion about foreign key in Groups.Drupal

=>
 [Add join/foreign key info to schema](http://groups.drupal.org/node/4328)

Comment: yep, it's a good discussion. not v. satisfactory, and it ended in 2009.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want: [References Module](http://drupal.org/project/references)